# How to aggregate junit test suite results into a single report run by gradle?

Tags: gradle, junit, build.gradle

I have a junit test suite that runs 4 test classes. When I run the test suite using gradle it creates 4 html reports, 1 for each test class in the suite. I'm new to gradle, is there a way to have gradle combine the results into a single html report?

Here is my test suite.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses([
    TestClass1.class,
    TestClass2.class,
    TestClass3.class,
    TestClass4.class,
])

class MyTestSuite {
}
```

In my gradle.build file I the following test method.

```
test {
  include("com/geb/tests/MyTestSuite.class")
  jvmArgs '-Dsomevariabe=someValue'
}
```

I run my test suite with the gradle command: `gradle :web-tests:test`

Then when the test suite has completed running there are 4 html files created for each class. Saved in `web-tests\build\reports\tests\classes`

```
testClass1.html
testClass2.html
testClass3.html
testClass4.html
```

Each testClass.html file lists each test cases pass or fail status.

I'd like to have a single html file containing a combined list of all the test cases pass or fail statuses. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](https://github.com/kncept/junit-reporter) can help you. Add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.kncept.junit.reporter:junit-reporter:2.1.0'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.kncept.junit.reporter' version '2.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.kncept.junit.reporter'

junitHtmlReport {
    // The maximum depth to traverse from the results dir.
    // Any eligible reports will be included
    maxDepth = 5
    
    // Directory where to search (exact or relative to build path)
    testResultsDir = '/path/to/root/of/project'
    // Where to output 
    testReportsDir = 'reports/junit'
    
    // Fail build when no XML files to process
    failOnEmpty = true
}
```

Now build the report with:
`./gradlew junitHtmlReport`

Creates an HTML report of all JUnit XML files it finds to `./reports/junit`. Note that this combines files like `TEST-*.xml` and not the html files.